# django several settings for local and production

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I have a project that may be started on local machine with `./manage.py runserver` and on the remote server with uwsgi. I have two settings files: settings (for local machine) and prod_settings. So when I start project with uwsgi I simply use this option

`env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=prod_settings`

But sometimes I have to know what module is currently active. I can check `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` key but think that it is not the True way. Tried to google something but found nothing yet.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: do you really need to know which settings module is active? or do you actually need to know if you're running production or local? if the latter then maybe just set a flag or use the sites framework.

Comment: I really should know the module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your settings files:

```
import os
SETTINGS_MODULE = os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

(or whatever you want)

but if it's just for debugging, that's not that much of an improvement wrt/ reading env["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"].

Comment: Thanks, I'll take your solution.